# Powershell -creplace doesn't find Expression at end of line

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, newline, match

I'm trying to find and replace some text at the end of line with Powershell. (ascii, txt, windows) I need to do this with a given script, which is already used for string replace:

```
$inputText = [system.IO.File]::ReadAllText("Text.txt")

$regex = '\\DE$|\DE_02'

$regex > test.txt

$th = [system.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt")

foreach($expression in $th) {

 if ($expression -eq 'EOF') { break }

 $parts = $expression.Split("|")

 if ($parts.Count -eq 2) {

     $inputText = $InputText -creplace $parts

     echo $inputText | out-file "Text_neu.txt" -enc ascii
 }
}
```

The cmdlet works fine so far, but cannot match the end of line ($) -.-
I also tried `r`n instead of $ but didn't work...

When I try like this:

```
$inputText = [system.IO.File]::ReadAllText("Text.txt")

$inputText.Replace("\DE\`r\`n","\DE_02\`r\`n") | Out-File Text_neu.txt
```

it's al replaced correctly.

How can I change the existing script so that it  will work also?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your script correctly, but I think your problem is, you are replacing on the whole text and not on single rows.

So `$` is not the end of a row (`\r\n`) **it will per default match on the end of the string!**

You can modify this behaviour by using the inline modifier `(?m)`. This will change the behaviour of `$` to match the end of the row.

Try

```
$regex = '(?m)\\DE$|\DE_02'
```

as you regular expression.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! this might be the problem here... it doesn't work like you proposed, but now I know where to look for solutions =)

Comment: oh, now i got it! it's just as you said with \`r\`n instead of $ ^^ THANK YOU!!! =)

Comment: Additionally the `s` modifier makes `.` match also `\n` (or `\r\n` for that matter). It can also be used combined with `m` like `(?ms)` which is often what you want when working with multiline strings.